# Sharepoint Online 2013, Shared with Everyone and spo-grid-all-users

Tags: 2013, document-library, sharepoint-online, my-site

In `SPO E*` you have the personal `companyName-my.sharepoint.com` site.

In the new 2013 version there is the Skydrive link on the top of the page which opens your personal document library. By default that contains a folder named `Shared with Everyone` and by inspecting the sharing settings, it's shared with

```
c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/{GUID}
```

I have tried to figure out WHO actually this `all users` apply to but haven't got a clear answer.

Do you know who, by default, this includes? Is it `all users` within your organization or does it include also `external users`?

Comment: Not sure what your asking really, but All Users equals the claims user c:0(.s|true, which really means "All Authenticated users", no matter how they where authenticated

Comment: @RobertLindgren Well, there is a built-in user group within Sharepoint Online which is c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/{GUID}. I unable to figure out who specifically is included in that group.

Answer (score 2):

Got answer from Microsoft's `Office 365` -support:

> "I would like to inform you that `Shared with Everyone` -folder is for sharing documents with *only the users within your organization, not outside*."

Suppose that solves my question.

The support personnel also linked me to this document:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/share-items-in-skydrive-pro-HA102788380.aspx#_Toc335293702 which weirdly contradicts what they just said.

However, after carefully examining the situation, the Shared With Everyone, **by default**, is linked to `c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/{GUID}` which matches **exactly** the `Everyone except external users` group.

**So, summa summarum:**

- All Users = Everyone *except* external users.
- All Authenticated Users = Everyone *including* external users.

Answer (score 0):

In the pickers for Office 365, you should be able to find two users; "Everyone" and "Everyone except external users".

As far as I understand, the claims token you have provided matches "Everyone". That should mean that both internal and external users can access the "Shared with Everyone folder"

I found this thread helpful in checking this: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/191752.aspx